# ListView.SelectedItems.Count keeps returning 1

Tags: c#, listview

**Heres my code:**

```
    private void employeelist_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (employeelist.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            console.Text = employeelist.SelectedItems.Count.ToString(); // returns 1 it should return 3
        }
    }
```

**Here's my listview (employeelist) with fullrowselect = true**

```
id | username | password
1  | user1    | pass1
2  | user2    | pass2
3  | user3    | pass3
```

When i click on first row, employeelist.SelectedItems.Count should return 3, but it keeps returning 1

Comment: [`FullRowSelect` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.listview.fullrowselect(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't do what you are expecting, I think, its value is not related to your problem. `SelectedItems` contains Items, `FullRowSelect` affect how subitems selection is handled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do, is not to use the `SelectedItems`, but the `SubItems` Property of the [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.subitems(v=vs.110).aspx) for the given `ListViewItem` that was selected.

Then you can do like follows:

```
ListView.Items[selectedIndex].SubItems.Count;
```

Where, ofcourse, your `selectedIndex` is that which the user has clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to count. Your ListView's MultiSelect Property is probably set to false. Set MultiSelect to true if you want to select more than 1 item.

If you are just trying to count the total items in the ListView use:

```
employeelist.Items.Count;
```